# ngFlow to Forimidable node.js server

Tags: javascript, node.js, angularjs

I am just wondering if anyone has implemented the ng-flow Angular.js module back to a formidable node.js server. I have got communication working and the files downloading but I am having issues with how ng-flow works. It chunks the files into multiple smaller uploads in parallel. On the server side all of these chunks are received and saved. But I am not sure how to reconstruct the received chunks.

Thanks in Advance!
Rabid

Answer (score -1, accepted):

So I sorted out the issues I was having.

If anyone is interested in how its done, the short answer is its not... Or at least not that I could figure out. In the end I used an alternate library to ng-flow. The angular-file-upload by  nervgh.

[Angular File Upload Libary](https://github.com/nervgh/angular-file-upload)

Whilst I probably preferred how the ng-flow library was implemented (from a functionality perspective), I was able to achieve the same result with this library with a little work.